# Is there any way to get the device notification history?

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, android-notifications

I'm developing an usage statistics app and I'm wondering how other apps can access to the **devices notification history**.

Right now I'm working with `NotificationListenerService`, but this only can handle the new notifications received, not the past ones.
I've checked Android DOC and found some methods which are 'system only' , like `getHistoricalNotifications()`, or that require `ACCESS_NOTIFICATION` permission.

The thing is that there are a few apps out there which actually can access to notification history data.

Android DOC also shows a new API on Android Q called `NotificationStats` but is not available at the moment.

Any tips? Is this even possible in a non-hacky way?

Comment: I was just about to suggest NotificationListenerService.

Comment: I'm not sure a history is kept by the OS. I had to install a third party app to see a history, and it was only able to see notifications that I had received after installation.

Comment: @TaslimOseni NotificationListenerService can be used for make some summary of the new notifications you received since you installed the app. I'm talking about getting data of the notifications you received on week ago, when you did not have the application on your cell phone yet, for example.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Since I started developing this app I have been looking at some examples and there are some few apps that can get this history data. Apart from the Google official one.

Comment: I actually do not think it is possible. I don't think a log of notifications is stored by the OS for any reason.

Comment: @TaslimOseni Not so sure about that. Maybe those apps make use of Google Digital Wellbeing data. But as I said, there are some examples that can achieve this.

Comment: Okay then, I suggest you place a bounty on this question to draw more attention to it.

Comment: @NachoRamosSánchez Can you tell the name of the app, that is able to get the history of notifications.

Comment: @nkalra0123 Sure, ActionDash. Also Google Digital Wellbeing can do it, but that's a system app. I'm using Android Q beta, Pixel 2 XL, maybe that's relevant too. I recently installed ActionDash on an older device and it wasn't able to get notification history at the beginning. Maybe this app use new apis from Android Q or is getting some info from Google System app which was installed long before Action Dash.

Answer (score 1):

ActionDash shows this [image]

As mentioned by you getHistoricalNotifications is a system-level API only accessed by system apps, so  Google Digital Wellbeing being a system app can show these.

So I think there is no way to get a history of notifications for 3rd party apps.

```
/**
         * System-only API for getting a list of recent (cleared, no longer shown) notifications.
         *
         * Requires ACCESS_NOTIFICATIONS which is signature|system.
         */
        @Override
        public StatusBarNotification[] getHistoricalNotifications(String callingPkg, int count) {
            // enforce() will ensure the calling uid has the correct permission
            getContext().enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATIONS,
                    "NotificationManagerService.getHistoricalNotifications");

            StatusBarNotification[] tmp = null;
            int uid = Binder.getCallingUid();

            // noteOp will check to make sure the callingPkg matches the uid
            if (mAppOps.noteOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OP_ACCESS_NOTIFICATIONS, uid, callingPkg)
                    == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED) {
                synchronized (mArchive) {
                    tmp = mArchive.getArray(count);
                }
            }
            return tmp;
        }
```

Comment: Yes. They use NotificationListenerService to get future notifications, as I was doing. The strange thing is that in Android Q with Pixel 2 XL I haven't even given permission to notification access. I installed it and showed me notifications from past days and weeks. So maybe... it's some kind of hacky bug in beta release, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the app notification data when notification is received into the sql database and when you want the history of the respective application's notification, you can easily get all notification by putting a query into the sql database.

Comment: Read carefully my question. I know that I can store new notifications. I need old notifications; even when my app wasn't installed yet.